# How to trap ORA-02055, "distributed update operation failed; rollback required" and possibly get at the root cause

Tags: oracle11g

In a stored procedure on one Oracle server, I attempt to insert a record into a table on a second Oracle server and it fails with the exception "distributed update operation failed; rollback required"

Although my code is wrapped in a BEGIN EXCEPTION END, the error handler fails to trap the error.

I even threw it inside a second error handler with no effect.  Any idea why I can't catch this error.  The Procedure compiles without issue.

My primary objective is to catch the error so I can return something useful to my user.  In addition I want to get at the root of the error if at all possible.

Note 1: If I uncomment the line which raises the "Remote Error" then it is caught as intended.

Note 2: The connection to the remote server is solid as I can query it without issue.

Both servers are: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

```
BEGIN                                                                 
    begin
      --raise_application_error( -20001, 'Remote Error' );
      insert into RemoteSchema.RemoteObject@RemoteSystem
        (field_one, field_two)
        select value_one, value_two from dual;
     exception
       when others then
         raise_application_error( -20000, 'Remote Error:' || sqlerrm );
     end;
 exception
   when others then
     raise_application_error( -20000, 'Caught Remote Error:' || sqlerrm );
 end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more debugging a co-worker helped me to spot the problem.  The error message was confusing because the update was actually successful but that success meant that there was now an active transaction with a "distributed update".

When my code ran into a subsequent trivial error, Oracle raised the error message "distributed update operation failed; rollback required", because there was now a transaction that needed to be rolled back first before I could raise the following error.

In my debugging I did not see the full message which would have sent me in the right direction.